# Как обобщить сущность что-бы хранить свойство IsRemoved

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite, android-sqlite

Для того что-бы не удалять из базы данных запись, имеется свойство IsRemoved исходя из которого и идет отображение данных. Вопрос, как правильно его хранить ? Для каждой сущности добавлять IsRemoved? Или можно как-то наследовать от другой сущности что-бы убрать повторения ?

Comment: Не, Вас реально заботит объём дискового пространства, занимаемый однобайтовым полем? тем более что с очень большой вероятностью размер занимаемого дискового пространства не увеличится вообще...

Comment: Тут речь не об объёме, а каким образом можно упростить взаимодействие, чтобы руками в каждую таблицу где это необходимо не добавлять.

Comment: Повторений данных здесь нет. Условное решение с одной таблицей будет не простым, в него стоит вкладываться если объем таблиц за тысячу и требуется еще какая-то инфа при удалении. А так, сгенерировать скрипт на добавление столбца в таблицы и все.

Comment: Схема зависимости экземпляров сущностей либо дерево, либо сеть. Во втором случае вообще ни о каких повторах речи не идёт, в первом же реальные, не мнимые, повторы имеются лишь в случае пары экземпляров, связанные 1:1 (реально - 1:[0-1]), чего в реальных БД без вертикального шардинга практически не бывает (а в нём вопрос теряет смысл).